# Problem Icon display BottomTabNav React-native

Tags: react-native

i have a rendering problem with my icon on my bottomTab, i use react-native-vector-icons and Ionicons packages.
I have tried with several icons but still have the same result. I am enclosing some of my elements that will help you.

[image]
Here you can see the bad rendering

Also you can see the import here

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {Animated} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Setting from '../Settings/Setting';
import Decibel from '../Decibel';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import Classement from '../Classement/Classement';
import ChoixSport from '../ChoixEquipes/ChoixSport';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```

And my code here

```
render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Dashboard"
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeBackgroundColor: '#000000',
          activeTintColor: '#CFF932',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: '#000000',
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
              <Icon name="ios-home" size={size} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Setting} />
```

Thank you all for your time and help !

Answer (score 1):

You can see here

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6867

and here

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1117

that other users of React Native Vector Icons went through the same thing.

You can check the solution in this comment below

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1117#issuecomment-589958315

You need to check if you added this configuration to the Android part.

You can check more details in the documentation from React Native Vector Icons:

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried adding the code in app / build.gradle but it crashes the app.
error message = >>> 
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app

Comment: hey @LambertAugis , I need more information about the error. Probably before this message "command failed: gradlew.bat app" there is more information about it. Can you please share a screenshot of the terminal?